# Installing pre ordered game from Steam as soon as possible

Tags: steam, the-witcher-2

I have pre ordered The Witcher 2 some while ago with my Steam client. So far so good.

The game should be released to public on May 17<sup>th</sup> 2011 - great.

Now for the questions:

1. Can I somehow "schedule" the game installation so that it will install itself when available?
2. If can't schedule, I fear there will be huge load on the servers as everyone will try installing at once: what's the best approach to take?

Comment: You've hit upon one of the most fundamental flaws with Steam I'm afraid

Answer (score 18):

Such games on steam usually allow you to 'Preload' the game. Basically this means upto 2 weeks before the game is released you will be able to download the game but not be able to play it. The fully installed game will then be unlocked on release day allowing you to instantly play it.

Comment: 2-4 weeks might be generous.  Sometimes, it's only 2-4 days.  (Portal 2 preload hasn't dropped as of this writing.)

Comment: you might be right with that ... will edit my post

Comment: It depends on the game. I believe the Civilization V pre-load was a little over a week before the game was released.

Comment: Less than 2 days are left and no preload... :(